# Is it safe to assign nullptr to a function pointer variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I created a function that accepts a function pointer, e.g.

```
typedef CString(*GetLabelFunc)(const CSomeObject* const pObject);

void DoSomething(GetLabelFunc funcGetLabel);
```

The function may receive a null pointer and will return an empty string in that case. This works perfectly fine in MSVC++ 2010 when using NULL and nullptr as parameter as well - but I do not consider a successful compilation a safe harbor in such special cases ...

Now I wondered if passing `nullptr` is equivalent to `NULL` for function pointers. The reason why I am asking is that for instance `void*` does not accept function pointers (or it least it should not be used). So maybe there is a similar reason that nullptr should not be used for function pointers - meaning is it designed to work for object pointers only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, nullptr is specified to be convertible to the null pointer value for all pointer types, including function pointer types.

See [conv.ptr] 4.10/1 and [basic.compound] 3.9.2/3.